# Image to the left of text

Tags: html, css

I have the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btcof8wz/) where I have an image icon on the left of text like this:

```
 <img> <text goes here>
```

However, when the text overflows I want it to look like this:

```
 <img> <text goes here............
       .........>
```

Instead of like this:

```
 <img> <text goes here............
 .........>
```

How would I do this? Here is the current html I have:

```
<div class="para">
    <p style="margin:0 0 5px;line-height: 1.2;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px; color: #666666;"> 
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/0ybqQCBY/hand.png" style="width: 20px;height: 20px;display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;margin-right: 5px;">
        Join the waitlist 
        <a href="https://www.example.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#29abe2">here is some long text here is some long text here is some long text here is some long text here is some long text  </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

It current looks like this:
[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the two elements (image and text) inside a div and give it display flex, in that way it's like if they are two columns.

```
 <div class="para">
       <div style="display:flex">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/0ybqQCBY/hand.png" style="width: 20px;height: 20px;display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;margin-right: 5px;">
          <span>
          Join the waitlist <a href="https://www.example.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#29abe2">here is some long text here is some long text here is some long text here is some long text here is some long text  </a>
          </span>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This somewhat appears to work, might need some tweaking.

```
<div class="para">
    <p style="margin:0 0 5px;line-height: 1.2;font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 14px; color: #666666;"> 
     
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/0ybqQCBY/hand.png" style="width: 20px;height: 20px;display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;margin-right: 5px;">
        Join the waitlist 
        
        <a href="https://www.google.com" style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;margin-left: 20px;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: clip;white-space: nowrap;">S IS TEXTTHIS IS TEXTTHIS IS TEXTTHIS IS TEXTTHIS IS TEXTTHIS IS TEXTTHIS IS TEXTTHIS IS TEXTTHIS IS TEXTTHIS IS TEXT</a>
        
    </p>
</div>
```